# Google Places Autocomplete not working on iPhone

Tags: ios, angularjs, iphone

I am trying to implement autocomplete for cities using Google places for my website.

I have this code working on desktops and android devices, but on iPhones I can see the list of options in the drop down list and looks like I'm selecting it, but it doesn't populate the textbox.

Directive: I'm trying a few different things I Googled with no success in solving my issue.

```
app.directive('stopIt', function($timeout) {
    return {
        link: function(scope, element, attr) {

            $timeout(function() {
                var container = document.getElementsByClassName('pac-container')[0];
                container.setAttribute('data-tap-disabled', 'true');


                container.onclick = function() {
                     document.getElementById('city').blur();    
                };

                container.addEventListener('touchend', function(e) {
                      e.stopImmediatePropagation();
                });
            }, 500);

        }
    };
});
```

HTML:

```
<input id="city" name="city" type="text" ng-model="account_city" stop-it
       placeholder="Enter a location"  autocomplete="on" googleplace />
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using webView?

Usually maps/locations are managed with Xcode and google SDK
(note also you have to PAY to use google services).
If You use Apple services (in Apple SDKs) it's free.